# Problemas com write.csv e write.xlsx

Tags: r, packages

Uso o windows 64 bits, tenho o java instalado e defini o diretório de trabalho no R. Mas, ao rodar um código simples tal como:

```
teste <- data.frame(a=c(2,2),b=c(3,3))
write.csv2(teste,file = "teste.csv")
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  não é possível abrir a conexão
Além disso: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  não foi possível abrir o arquivo 'teste.csv': Permission denied
```

Se tento usar o código:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(data2, file="data2.xlsx", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Obtenho:

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
Além disso: Warning message:
In if (is.na(value)) { :
  a condição tem comprimento > 1 e somente o primeiro elemento será usado
```

Ambos os códigos funcionavam na minha máquina, normalmente. Pararam de funcionar de uma hora para outra. Já pesquisei em todas as páginas possíveis, reinstalei o R e o RStudio, já reiniciei a máquina, já troquei a pasta dos arquivos. Não sei mais como fazer para resolver isso! Alguém já passou por problema semelhante e pode me ajudar?

Comment: Parece um problema com a chamada ao java, confira se sua máquina possui o JDK instalado conforme cita a documentação do pacote: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.3

Comment: Como disse o Lucas parece um problema com o Java, qual o sistema você utiliza? Está salvando em qual diretório? Tem o java instalado?

Comment: Está rodando o R aonde? Definiu o diretório de trabalho? Você possui permissão de escrita para ele?

Comment: Estou rodando no windows, sim, tenho o Java instalado. O diretório de trabalho foi definido, tenho permissão total para escrita nele!

Comment: Você está setando o caminho do arquivo corretamente? Pois utilizando o R no windows você tem que passar o caminho com / e não com \. Exemplo: C:\ assim não funciona mas assim funciona: C:/

Comment: Estou setando corretamente, já fiz isso milhões de vezes. Como disse, já pesquisei em todos os fóruns possíveis, não dá para entender esse erro! Tem muita gente com o mesmo problema! Espero que quem deu "downvote" na pergunta nunca enfrente o mesmo problema!

Comment: Também não entendi o down vote na pergunta.Mas desse site eu não duvido nada. Tem gente que copia a sua solução, posta em cima e ainda leva os créditos. Da de tudo aqui

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente era o antivírus Avast que estava causando o problema. Desabilitei o mesmo por 10 min e reinstalei o pacote xlsx. Reiniciei o R e depois de 24h perdidas, consegui fazer voltar a funcionar! Espero que mais pessoas resolvam o problema com a mesma solução, após uma pesquisa enorme na internet, descobri que muitos já fizeram essa mesma pergunta!